# How to automatically insert an html tag into a react component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I am fetching HTML from my backend (generated by CKEditor) I am then using DangerouslySetInnerHTML to render said HTML like this :

```
 const parsed = DOMPurify.sanitize(album.description)
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML ={{ __html: parsed }} className={styles.albumDescription} </div>
```

It works fine and I'm able to render my HTML. However I'm having troubles with embed medias. CK editor returns the media link in a `<oembed />` tag.

What I would like to do is that each time there is a `<oembed />`, insert them into `<ReactPLayer />` component.

I understand I could probably use vanilla js DOM manipulation and use something like getElementsByTagName but I assume that's not great practice to do that in react.

Comment: " I assume that's not great practice to do that in react." So is using dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: @Salketer. I sanitize my input, but how should I go about rendering my html without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML then ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the DOM manipulation the challenge would be to verbatim replace all the attributes that `<oembed .... />` would have, not impossible though.

If the incoming html string is not HUGE (running in several MBs), a simple string regex manipulation should do the trick:

Option 1: If you are sure that it'll always be <oembed ... />, then the following works.

```
const desc = album.description;
oembed_2_player = desc.replaceAll(/\<oembed ([^\/]*)\/\>/gi,"<ReactPLayer $1 />"); 
const parsed = DOMPurify.sanitize(oembed_2_player)
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML ={{ __html: parsed }} className={styles.albumDescription} </div>
```

Option 2: If you expect <oembed ....> ...  & you want to translate it into <ReactPlayer ..same-as-in-oembed..> ..dito... then

```
const desc = album.description;
oembed_2_player = desc.replaceAll(/\<(oembed) ([^\>]*)\>([^\<]*)<\/\1\>/gi,"<ReactPLayer $2>$3</ReactPLayer>");
const parsed = DOMPurify.sanitize(oembed_2_player)
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML ={{ __html: parsed }} className={styles.albumDescription} </div>
```

Hope this helps